# Sort and Move Data Between Tabs Based On Verification Step

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Evening everyone!

Below I have the link to my test sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12I9u5XoYBQ7qeaTtqBRjEaz8YpLK04DgHlLnSuw4IDo/edit#gid=0

My goal, works between two tabs on the same sheet. One tab, "Reference" has a list of sorted data with a unique shipment reference attached. In an offset column, I have the unique shipments populated, with a checkbox next to each unique shipment label.

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YnCq.jpg)

Is there a way via with a menu add on or activated cell script, to move all items from columns A:E, that match the selected the checkbox next to a specific shipment reference, onto the second tab labeled "Processing"? I would vision that once items are removed to be transferred from Tab 1 to 2, that the rows will all shift up to avoid blank space, and items being added to Tab 2 will add to the next open row of the doc.

Please let me know if this makes sense and if anyone has any ideas, thank you!

Below is what we had so far:

```html
function Transfer() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(sh.getName() == "Reference" && e.range.columnStart == 8 &&  e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    let rg = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,5)
    let vs = rg.getValues();
    const osh = e.source.getSheetByName("Processing");
    osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,5).setValues(vs);
    rg.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the script so far! It works almost perfect as I was thinking, but is there a way to pull all values that match when the check box is selected? Ie. currently it pulls one row at a time if a shipment ID matches the source range, but can it be where "If check verification is selected, pull ALL rows that match the adjacent shipment ID to the second tab"? I wanted to use the unique filter as the "If a row between A:E contains the shipment ID, when box is selected, pull all rows that have the same shipment ID to the second tab". Hope this is possible!

Comment: Hi. Your question should be able to stand on its on. But a volunteer needs to open your spreadsheet to understand your data and the checkbox. Would you please add a screenshot, or a text table to your question.

Comment: Currently it's setup to handle them one at a time as they get checked but if you don't wish to use onEdit and check several of them and then run a script that could work as well

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Tedinoz, I added the recommended edits to the question, apologies for the confusion or hassle!